# Iterating over dataframe and get columns as new dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a set of dataframes from one big dataframe. Theses dataframes consists of the columns of the original dataframe in this manner:
1st dataframe is the 1st column of the original one,
2nd dataframe is the 1st and 2nd columns of the original one,
and so on.
I use this code to iterate over the dataframe:

```
for i, data in enumerate(x):
    data = x.iloc[:,:i]
    print(data)
```

This works but I also get an empty dataframe in the beginning and an index vector I don't need.
any suggestions on how to remove those 2?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of enumerating the dataframe, since you are not using the outcome after enumerating but using only the index value, you can just iterate in the `range` 1 through the number of columns added one, then take the slice `df.iloc[:, :i]` for each value of `i`, you can use list-comprehension to achieve this.

```py
>>> [df.iloc[:, :i] for i in range(1,df.shape[1]+1)]
[  A
0  1
1  2
2  3,    
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  4
2  3  6]
```

The equivalent traditional loop would look something like this:

```py
for i in range(1,df.shape[1]+1):
    print(df.iloc[:, :i])
    
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  4
2  3  6
```

Comment: thanks so much for the help! i have another question though, what if i want it to move 2 columns at a time instead of 1? i tried changing the first line to +2 but it still jumps 1 at a time.

Comment: @OmerDavidi, then you need to pass `step` parameter to `range` function, the modified code will look something like this:  `[df.iloc[:, :i] for i in range(1,df.shape[1]+1, 2)]`

Answer (score 0):

you can also do something like this:

```
data = {
    'col_1': np.random.randint(0, 10, 5),
    'col_2': np.random.randint(10, 20, 5),
    'col_3': np.random.randint(0, 10, 5),
    'col_4': np.random.randint(10, 20, 5),
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

all_df = {col: df.iloc[:, :i] for i, col in enumerate(df, start=1)}

# For example we can print the last one
print(all_df['col_4'])
    col_1   col_2   col_3   col_4
0   1   13  5   10
1   8   16  1   18
2   6   11  5   18
3   3   11  1   10
4   7   14  8   12
```